# Duplicating Tables During Migration in Postgresql from ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

This is my first project on PostgreSQL, and that's why I'm not very proficient with it. Previously, I've always used SQL Server.

Anyway, I have a problem where, for some reason, during the database migration, my tables are duplicating. For example, I have a model in the project called `PsychologistProfile`, and in the context, it is listed as `_PsychologistProfiles`. During the database migration, I expect to see a single table created as `_PsychologistProfiles`. However, I also end up with `PsychologistProfile`, even though I don't specify it in the context. This happens with all the tables in the database.

Interestingly, I noticed that I have two contexts in the project, `ApplicationDbContext` and `IdentityDbContext`. When I migrate the first one, all the tables are created as they should be. However, as soon as I create a migration for `IdentityDbContext`, the existing tables such as `PsychologistProfile` are created. I looked at the `Constraints` tab in the database for the tables, and the table `_PsychologistProfiles` has `FK__PsychologistProfiles_User_UserId`, while `PsychologistProfile` has `FK_PsychologistProfile_AspNetUsers_UserId`.

My model classes - `PsychologistProfile`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PsychoLinkerWebAPI.Models
{
    public class PsychologistProfile
    {
        [Key]
        public string PsychologistId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string AboutMe { get; set; }
        public string SessionFeedback { get; set; }
        public string YearsOfExperience { get; set; }
        public string EducationPlace { get; set; }
        public string YearOfGraduation { get; set; }
        public string WorkHours { get; set; }
        public string BreakDuration { get; set; }
        public string TimeBeforeBooking { get; set; }
        public string SessionDuration { get; set; }
        public string SessionPrice { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<WorkSchedule> WorkSchedules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`User`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace PsychoLinkerWebAPI.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual PsychologistProfile PsychologistProfile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UPD

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<PsychologistProfile> _PsychologistProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkSchedule> _WorkSchedules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkInterval> _WorkIntervals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne(u => u.PsychologistProfile)
                .WithOne(pp => pp.User)
                .HasForeignKey<PsychologistProfile>(pp => pp.UserId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the part with the underline?

Comment: @nbk What do you mean? database context?

Comment: usually the public class defines the table, so i was wandering where you define _PsychologistProfile

Comment: @nbk Ah, I see what you mean. I've clarified the question.

Comment: ok, what are those declarations for? i cannot see the use. If your remove them you will not have duplicate tables